# codeigniter site wont login on different computers

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, session-cookies

I have a basic site I made for practice purposes and have built a login/member type functionality with it. The weird thing is that when I try to login on different computers, some will login in properly while others will just redirect me and not log me in although my credentials are good. I am thinking maybe it is different security settings in the browsers for storing sessions, cookies? But all the browsers I tested on have cookies enabled but the site and login feature will only work for some. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once and it was caused by the browser. If you redirect the user after login with

```
redirect(url);
```

try to replace that with

```
redirect(url, 'refresh');
```

IE doesn't play well with cookies and header redirects.

Comment: On one of my computers my site only logins  correctly with firefox. chrome and internet explorer just redirect me w/o logging me in

Comment: It would be useful if you share some code, otherwise I'm only guessing.

Comment: It wont let me edit original post and only lets me have about 500 charecters to show code which isn't enough. Do I need to repost a new question/